# What is the relationship between non-Reciprocal and non-Hermite?

Tags: classical-mechanics, condensed-matter

In paper[Non-Hermitian morphing of topological modes], the author realizes a non-Hermite ssh model by constructing an active mechanical lattice, the united cell consisting of 2 sites A、B.
$$
\mathrm{d}^2\theta_{l,A}/\mathrm{d}t^2=v(\theta_{l-1,B}-\theta_{l,A})+w(\theta_{l,B}-\theta_{l,A})\\
\mathrm{d}^2\theta_{l,B}/\mathrm{d}t^2=v(\theta_{l,A}-\theta_{l,B})+w(\theta_{l+1,A}-\theta_{l,B})+\delta \theta_{l,A}\\
$$
[image]
Thus the mechanical operator of it is Non-Hermite:
$$
H\left(k\right)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & v+w \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} k} \\v+\left(w+\delta\right) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} k} & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
In paper[Odd elasticity], the author constructs a 2D lattice, the force on each site is：
$$
F(r)=(-k\hat{r}+k^a \hat{\phi})\delta r
$$
[image]

Where $\delta r = r- r_0 $ is the radial displacement from the equilibrium length $r_0$, and and $\hat{\phi}$ are the unit vectors parallel and perpendicular to the bond, respectively.

The interaction between sites is pairwise **(I naively think, pairwise is reciprocal),** while the overdamped equation of lattice motion is non-Hermite:
$$
-i \omega \Gamma\left(\begin{array}{l}
u_{\|} \\
u_{\perp}
\end{array}\right)=-q^{2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
B+\mu & K^{\circ} \\
-K^{\circ}-A & \mu
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
u_{\|} \\
u_{\perp}
\end{array}\right)
$$
Where $u_{\|}$is the longitudinal displacement and $u_{\perp}$ is the transverse displacement.

I want to know the relationship between （1）pairwise force （2）non-reciprocal (3)non-Hermite system.

Thanks for your help~

Reference:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJURH.png):Wang, W., Wang, X. & Ma, G. Non-Hermitian morphing of topological modes. Nature 608, 50–55 (2022). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-022-04929-1

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBUUS.png):Scheibner, C., Souslov, A., Banerjee, D. et al. Odd elasticity. Nat. Phys. 16, 475–480 (2020). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41567-020-0795-y

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified it. But I'm not familiar with this system, my question may still be vague.